# Spring Security HTTPS

Tags: spring, security, authentication, https

I have the problem, that Spring Security is redirecting me to much. So the browser can't build up the side. Whats wrong with my code?

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest()
                    .requiresSecure()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

I thought, that the user would be able to access to "localhost:8585/login", because of the .antMatchers("/login").permitAll() ?

Comment: where is login located ?

Comment: order may have influence here, try to put whole block with antMatchers("/login") before block with "authenticated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order matters here

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()            
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
                .and() 
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .anyRequest()
                    .requiresSecure()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```